# Calculate the arc length of the curve $8x=y^4+\frac{2}{y^2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, curves

I need the integral to calculate the arc length of the curve $8x=y^4+\frac{2}{y^2}$ from $y=1$ to $y=2$.

For now I only need to set up the integral with the formula

$$ L=\int _a^b\sqrt{1+(y')^2}dx$$

but the function that I have is equal to $x$ like this:
$$x=\frac{y^4+\frac{2}{y^2}}{8}$$
As a next step I have made the derivative of that function with respect to $y$ and the result is the following:
$$(f')=\frac{y^6-1}{2y^3}$$

I need help on how to create the integral with its limits of integration having the function already derived as $dy$

The reason why I only need to define the integral is because I am going to solve it with a numerical method in matlab

Comment: Names of variables are relative - $L = \int_{y=}^{y=} \sqrt{1+(f')^2} \, dy$. Compute $1+(f')^2$ and you'll recognize a square.

Comment: I thought it was this but I'm not sure $ L=\int _1^2\sqrt{1+(\frac{y^6-1}{2y^3})^2}dy$

Answer (score 3):

Note the arclength formula can be written as the following forms,

$$ L=\int_A^B\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}=\int_{x_A}^{x_B}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx=\int_{y_A}^{y_B} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}dy$$

In this problem you need to use the last expression, and plug in your derivative

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{y^6-1}{2y^3}$$

Comment: Like this: $ L=\int _1^2\sqrt{1+(\frac{y^6-1}{2y^3})^2}dy$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: $L=\int _1^2\sqrt{1+(\frac{y^6-1}{2y^3})^2}dy=\frac{33}{16}$